# How can I prevent overlap of two "spanX" divs when shrinking the screen in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the `responsive` layout of Twitter Bootstrap 2.3. I have a `span9 row-fluid` div containing two `span4` divs.

To test the fluidity of the screen, I'm shrinking the window. There comes a specific point at which the right `span4` overlaps with the left `span4`. If I keep shrinking the window, it will stack appropriately. But I want it to stack appropriately before overlapping. Is the functionality I want built into Bootstrap and I'm just not doing it right?

Any help is appreciated of course!

Comment: can you please post the code you have tried .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe double check that you are using the bootstrap responsive css and that there isn't a blip in your HTML. I'm not completely clear on your layout, but here's a working example of something close : http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/RMUmW/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    nested span4
                </div>
                 <div class="span4">
                    nested span4
                </div>
                 <div class="span4">
                    nested span4
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end nested row -->

        </div> <!-- end span9 -->
        <div class="span3">
            span 3
        </div> <!-- end span3 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->

</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Good luck!

Comment: It didnt help. but after reading this answer, i went back and rewrote the html and my issue is gone. upvoted for the clear answer !